Cómo hacer para que sólo se vea una parte de la URL de la web
Estoy haciendo un CRUD y me gustaría que en la URL sólo se mostrase la parte que a mi me interesa y no toda la dirección. ¿Se puede hacer esto?
Pongo un ejemplo, para que quede más claro, en el navegador se muestra lo siguiente en la URL:
http://localhost/webs/CRUD/Vista/form_Editar.php?id=FDA966

y yo lo que deseo es que se muestre sólo
http://localhost/webs/CRUD


Pues en lugar de pasar los parametros por GET pásalos por POST y rectoca el .htaccess para que te redireccione el CRUD a CRUD/Vista/form_Editar.php.  O bien, si vas a tener que ejecutar más scripts en esa carpeta, solo te queda hacerlo por ajax.

Por un lado, la etiqueta HTML no hace sentido aquí, HTML es el lenguaje de markup y poco tiene que ver con URL's y cosas así.  Por otro, creo que debieras incluir en la pregunta el por qué querrías hacer algo así. Hay maneras de lograrlo, y hay frameworks que trabajan así, pero usualmente, por temas de usabilidad, se va en la otra dirección, es decir, aunque no recargues la página, vas agregando cosas a la URL para que el usuario pueda compartirla o volver al mismo punto sin tener que hacer toda la interacción previa. Es parte básica para el funcionamiento del historial, etc.

Debes tener un buen motivo para querer romper eso...

Puedes usar replaceState para cambiar la URL desde javascript, ejemplo:
history.replaceState(null,null,"webs/CRUD");

Yo no lo recomiendo, la URL es parte de la usabilidad del sitio. Por ejemplo, un usuario puede requerir que otro usuario edite un "item", le envía la URL (/webs/CRUD/Vista/form_Editar.php?id=FDA966) y ya. Pero en tu caso ahora tiene que dar instrucciones: "entra a /webs/CRUD/, busca el item FDA966, presiona el botón editar, etc"
He escuchado de algunos (no digo que sea tu caso) que lo hacen por "seguridad", pero si la seguridad del sitio depende de conocer o no la URL, es que está todo mal.
